# Randomized Array Will Not Update

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I'm writing code where there will be several actions in an array.

```
var randomStringsWriting = [
'Write about ' + randomObjectsPlural,
'Think about ' + randomObjectsPlural,
'Love ' + randomObjectsPlural
```

the "randomObjectsPlural" variable is another array with nouns

```
var randomObjectsPluralList = [
'cats',
'dogs',
'people',
]
```

In order to make it easier for me to write one variable instead of an equation, I set this initially (Note that THIS is the variable in the initial array, and not "randomObjectsPluralList")

```
 var randomObjectsPlural = randomObjectsPluralList[0]
```

I would like the text to update whenever I click, so I wrote this function:

```
$("#screen" ).click(function(){
randomObjectsPlural =  randomObjectsPluralList[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomObjectsPluralList.length)];
});
```

Oddly, when I click to randomize, the same "randomObjectsPlural" variable is kept, despite the click to randomize.  For example, the screen would eventually display...

```
Write about cats
Think about cats
Love cats
```

...when I would want something more like

```
Write about cats
Think about people
Love dogs
```

The only way that the noun would change is if I refreshed the page.  What exactly is happening here?

Comment: Can you post a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?  Please?

Comment: A click changes the variable value. It does not change the contents of the strings array. That array's value is set when the equal sign puts the list of strings formed by concatenation into it. It won't change until you do that again. Further, that same code uses the same value to concatenate into all the strings. So they will always be the same.

Comment: So how exactly do I fix/get around/rewrite this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you have wired all this up but when you `click` you have to randomise each item again and again.

What you have shown so far would indicate that you only set the `randomStringsWriting` array ones at the start, hence you only update it ones at page load.

You are also setting each item to `randomObjectsPlural` but it seems you are only setting the variable up ones. You would need to randomise a new `randomObjectsPlural` for each one.

Again, as I have no idea how you have actually wired it all up below is a demo to achieve what you are looking for.

The below is an example. You still will need to take the logic and adapt it into your own implementation.

Assuming the following HTML:

```
<button id="screen">Click</button>
<div id="output"></div>
```

The following JavaScript would do the trick:

```
var getRandomListItem = function () {
    return randomObjectsPluralList[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomObjectsPluralList.length)]
};

var randomObjectsPluralList = [
    'cats',
    'dogs',
    'people']

$("#screen").click(function () {
    var randomStringsWriting = [
    'Write about ' + getRandomListItem(),
    'Think about ' + getRandomListItem(),
    'Love ' + getRandomListItem()]

    $('#output').html(randomStringsWriting.join('<br />'));
});
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/QBY66/) - Randomizing the string values

---

As you are only picking a random value out of a possible 3 it is very likely off course that you still get all 3 random values to be the same.

If you want random + different then you also need to keep track of each value which already has been selected until all have been picked, then re-set the tracker but that is a slightly more involved process.

Comment: This looks like the answer, but I'm not terribly sure how to implement it.  I built a jfiddle, but elements of it can be extraneous because sometimes it didn't work when I took certain elements out, so hopefully it is readable.  http://jsfiddle.net/Uh4xw/

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your final design intention is but I amended the code a little so `randomStringsWriting` is now also a function. that way when called it goes and sets the values random again each time as it is calling `getRandomListItem` for each value. [**Your updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qWdS2/) I hope this is more closely to what you were looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much for putting in the time to help me out with this!  I wish I upvote more than once, haha.

Comment: @AlexanderLozada: You are more than welcome. Glad that it helped you out.